# How can I disable hash url entry in jQm while still allowing my blur event to fire?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQm, when I have `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;`:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function (){
    // Disable hash navigation
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
});
```

My blur event is not firing:

```
$('.ui-selectmenu-list').on('blur', function(){
    console.log('blur');
}
```

When I remove the `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;`, my blur event fires consistently with no issue.

How can I disable hash url entry for navigation while still allowing my blur event to fire?

Update: Other blur events on inputs work either way, so I have a feeling this issue is only related to jQuery mobile enhanced selectmenus. Without `$.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;`, I can see `&ui-state=dialog` being applied and removed from the URL in the address bar. With it, nothing is added to the URL, but the selectmenu is still opened with no issue. I have a feeling this might be what jQm is using to determine blur states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the blur event would fire when I would click off the selectmenu list (closing it), but not when I would make a selection that caused it to close. I solved this by listening for the blur on the anchor element controlling the selectmenu, which fired when expected.